# Backward ssh connection via Forward https connection (https-tunnel)

Tags: sockets, nginx, ssh, https, tunnel

I need a construction that make possible to tunnel backward SSH via forward HTTPS. I tried to draw on a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNfuv.png) what I have to get. The picture shows 4 steps that explain what and how I want to make.

How it can be done? Is there a ready solution maybe?

Comment: does your server have an ssh server too (but with firewalled port)? if yes then you could make reverse tunnel via https proxy (i.e. connect to the server's sshd and map new tcp port at server which ssh client at server could use to connect to remote host back). I assume you do not trust remote devices to ssh to the server. to avoid this mistrust you could run sshd in a docker container to isolate server env from tunnel. BTW, this question has nothing to do with software development so it does not belong here

Comment: have a look at https://superuser.com/a/1444868/1117244

Comment: No, the Server does not have SSH service. It has HTTPS service. It can be possible to administrate Remote host via SSH from Server side but only via HTTPS tunnel. So at first the Remote host initiate HTTPS-tunnel to the Server, and next step Server connect SSH to the Remote host via HTTPS-tunnel.

Comment: you need some extra protocol and service to make listening ports at server - you will be able to configure your nginx for CONNECT method to proxy your connection to such service. It does not matter what service you will use. it could be sshd or stun service. take a look at generic answer to your question - https://serverfault.com/a/804674/550521 - there OP states that they ended up with saltstack to connect to the devices back. Most likely it is what you need.